# how to retrieve only field(field name ) as list array from FireStore in android?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to  retrieve field as List Array from Firestore

[image]

in this Horror field is "map" I want to retrieve  all  field in  HINDI document as Array
as shown in the image

[image]

```
    public class HindiStory extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String TAG = "HindiStory";

        List<String> list;


        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        private DocumentReference hindiStoryref = db.collection("story").document("HINDI");

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_hindi_story);




        }

        public void hmoral(View v){
            hindiStoryref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        list = new ArrayList<>();
                        Map<String, Object> map = task.getResult().getData();
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
                            list.add(entry.getKey());
                            Log.d(TAG, entry.getKey());
                    }


                }



                }
            });


    }


    public  void hromantic(View v){

    }
}
```

*I want to retrieve on a button click

and use this array data  in listview  in another activity* thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bellow code it will work for you

```
hindiStoryref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.getResult() != null && task.getResult().exists() && task.getResult().getData() != null) {
                    list.addAll(task.getResult().getData().keySet()); //Adding list of field list into list object
                    Log.d("arrayKeys size", list.size() + "");
                    Log.d("arrayKeys size", list.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast with hashmap.

```
HashMap<String, Object> categoriesMap = (HashMap)task.getResult().getData()
```

Also

```
 list.add(entry.getKey());
```

You can use

```
categoriesMap.keySet();
```

To get all value from Hashmap

This is how i have done to retrieve the HasMap values :

```
  ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + doc);
                HashMap<String, String> categoriesMap = (HashMap)doc.getData().get("categories");
                mCategories.addAll(categoriesMap.keySet());
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: hey haresh  

I didn't  get    .get("catagories")  and  mCategories
what is it here